# "RhostsRSAAuthentication"

Tags: ssh

I am a Linux/Ubuntu novice. I just finished installing the latest distribution upgrade 18.04 and during the process I was asked if I wanted to keep my old `sshd_config` file which I did. After the upgrade was complete I tried logging in to a remote server with `ssh` and received the following message:

```
The authenticity of host 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:33WUUSJS2nLSwsUsiA3/S5gWMFXcIg/Q/MNSMLCr5tI.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
```

SSH will not accept my password.

Comment: Can you log in from a different machine?

Comment: @j-money: Regarding [your edit suggestion](/review/suggested-edits/885869), knowledge of the fingerprint in question is useless to anyone but those who already encountered the key in question – and those only gain the additional knowledge of the issue in question related to that key.

Comment: @j-money In addition to what David said, if there were actually sensitive personal info in the question, it should be flagged for moderator attention. Editing it out leaves it still available in the [edit history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1082361/revisions).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please run `ssh` with the `-vvv` flag and [edit] your question to include 1) the exact `ssh` command as well as the new output (mask the host name if you wish) and 2) the content of `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and `~/.ssh/config` if they exist. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you all for commenting. Apparently I did not need to include the ip address, just the name of the remote server. so "ssh name". That did the trick, I was able to connect.

Comment: @Robert Glad you got it sorted! Please write an answer (yes, you can answer your own question) so that your knowledge could help someone else (or even yourself in the future).